# Generating a Java webservice which returns a png file

Tags: java, web-services, webservice-client

I have written a piece of Java code which gets an string as an argument and calls some R scripts to be run, scrip is going to generate a .PNG file( which is the result of the service). I am supposed to expose this as a webservice and then later it will be consumed by a website (as service client).

Could anyone please give me some pointer for how to do this? Is there any tutorial to do that?

Comment: is the PNG generated or this PNGs exists?

Comment: @PbxMan the PNG file is going to be generated by the script.(However it takes some time to be generated because of processing delay).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't going to be much different than designing a web service that receives any input and returns any output. The only difference here would be that you'll be returning binary data, rather than textual data.

If you are returning binary data, then the return value of the Java method should be a byte array (`byte[]`). Once you get the `png` file from the R script, read it fully into a byte array and return that array.

When you generate a Web Service layer on top of this Java code, the "glue" code converting binary data into textual format will be generated for you.

The problem that the `png` file isn't completing instantly isn't related to web services. Your Java code calls the R script, waits for it to finish, and then reads the file into a byte array. As long as the web service *client* is willing to wait for the entire cycle to end, there is no problem. Just ensure that the web service *client* is configured with proper timeout settings.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I Just want to know what should be return type of the java function, and how can I retrieve it from the webpage which will be the client of the service, Can u explain a little a bit more.

Comment: My other problem is that the R script generates the png and write is in a folder. But it does not do it immediately, it takes some unknown time. isn't it a problem?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done it before but you could output the .png file to a byte[] and then use The [Base64 class in Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html#encodeBase64String%28byte%5B%5D%29) to convert that to a String and return that in the XML response.